# Obtener valor de la vista blade de Laravel en componente Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

Estoy implementando livewire en una vista blade, el esquema es el siguiente:

**view blade**

```
    @extends('seccion-principal')

    @section('content') 
    
        {{$propiedad->id}}
    
    
         Dentro de la vista uso el componente de livewire
         @livewire('componente')
    
    @endsection
```

Quiero pasarle al componente el id. Algo así:

```
@livewire('componente', $propiedad->id)
```

Y veo que no es posible pero tampoco encuentro como se puede hacer algo así.

**El error :**

> Argument 1 passed to
> Livewire\LivewireManager::resolveClassMethodDependencies() must be of
> the type array, integer given, called in

¿Alguien conoce si existe una forma de realizar este procedimiento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el error que obtienes, debes pasarle un array como argumento. Deberías intentarlo de esta manera, tal y como lo dice la [documentación](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/rendering-components):

```
@livewire('componente', ["id" => $propiedad->id])
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, había visto eso en la documentación pero me daba un error y me di cuenta que era por que debería realizar un mount. Por lo tanto como me indicas y agregando el mount funciona perfecto. public $agendar, $valorId;

 public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->valorId = $id;
    }